# R Markdown equivalent in SAS

Tags: r, sas, knitr

i wonder if there is a equivalent of R Markdown in SAS? Or how to do so in SAS? I want to have colored SAS code and its result below.

link to R Markdown: http://rstudio.org/docs/authoring/using_markdown

Comment: Just do it in R. You know you want to ;-)

Comment: +1 on using R. But I can understand that there might be circumstances where SAS is required, e.g. by the customer.

Comment: But if i want to do training materials for SAS i need to use SAS :) it would be better to have something similar for SAS.

Comment: I think it is entirely possible to run SAS with `knitr` + markdown if you can define a proper language engine: http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/engines/ although it sounds ironic... Just note `knitr` is not restricted to R only; in theory you can use any languages as long as you know how to call them through R.

Comment: Though it is not what you asked for, there is something akin for LaTeX and SAS: SASweave. http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~rlenth/SASweave/ Perhaps the infrastructure could be adapted to output Markdown instead of LaTeX.

Comment: I've struggled with this, but found that using pandoc and using SQL language highlighting covered most functions (but then again, I use proc SQL mostly!). To specify the language of a code block use ```{.SQL}.

Comment: There is a StatRep package for Latex http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings12/324-2012.pdf but it's still what i wanted to achieve...(thans to Cynthia from SAS https://communities.sas.com/message/132901#132901)

Comment: It might be a bit much to expect your students to learn Emacs, but there's excellent support for literate SAS programming through the combination of [org babel](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/) (the literate programming part) and [Emacs Speaks Statistics](http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html#ESS-for-SAS) (the SAS part).

Answer (score 4):

[Geshi](http://qbnz.com/highlighter/demo.php) supports SAS. I think it does a pretty nice job. It is the highlighter in Wikimedia and is also available as a Perl module.

It shouldn't be too hard (famous last words :)) to connect Geshi to Markdown. You could obtain the plots by running a console SAS job. However, I think that as of 2012 (SAS 9.3), you would have to automate the workflow yourself. When one of the markup languages becomes dominant you will probably see more formal support.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://support.sas.com/publishing/pubcat/chaps/59602.pdf) describes how to generate reports using SAS. From skimming the pdf it seems that you can integrate SAS analyses and text:

> With SAS procedures, SAS DATA steps, and SAS features such as the
>   Output  Delivery System (ODS) and the macro facility, you have the
>   tools to succeed at  writing programs that analyze your data and
>   create reports

Comment: There is an option ods text but it don't do what i want which is colored syntax.